# RoundhousE - Change login used by scripts scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment, roundhouse

I am trying to set up roundhouse deployment scripts.  I am running into a little trouble with remote logins.  We need to login with an sql account (not machine or domain - this is against MSSQL 2008R2 on Server 2008 R2 SP1) when creating the database on remote servers.  Is there any way to provide different credentials for roundhouse to connect and run scripts as, I am not seeing it in the documentation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the connection string instead of the server name and db name, you can then set the credentials as well.

From: https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions

There is the --connectionstring (or -c for short):

```
-c, --cs, --connstring, --connectionstring=VALUE
ConnectionString - As an alternative to ServerName and Database - You can provide an entire connection string instead.
```

So you could do something like this:

```
-c=server=localhost;uid=SomeUser;pwd=Secret;database=MyDB;
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that page.  Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No worries. It took me forever to even realize that there was documentation.

Comment: Documentation used to only be in the word document files that were included in the source. Started moving it to a wiki back in June.

Comment: @ferventcoder - Thanks for moving it to the wiki. It's much easier to use there.