# Problems with --CSA parameter Roundhouse

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, teamcity, roundhouse

I am having problems authenticating to my sql server with roundhouse and Teamcity. Teamcity is running as the local system account, so the cmd shell will open under the local sytem. When I pass in rh.exe -d=DB -s=SQLSERVER -csa=uid=DOMAIN\USER;pwd=PASSWORD ...
I get an error that logging in under the local machine name is not a valid login.

I then tried the format listed here [RoundhousE - Change login used by scripts scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375927/roundhouse-change-login-used-by-scripts-scripts) , and I get an error about a failed login for the specific user. I know that the password is correct, so I'm confused as to why it would not be working now.

RH.exe version 0.8.5.0
Teamcity version 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out a workaround on the TeamCity side. By switching my buildAgent to the account that I normally use for deployment, I can successfully authenticate.

The format that I use is 
rh.exe -d=param -s=param -f=param -vf=param

If you have any other solutions that involve the exact syntax for Roundhouse, I would still greatly appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question but is that your bare command args?

It might be better to enclose those in double quotes -csa="COMPLETE Connection String, end with ;"

Comment: I can't remember if I did or not. The solution that worked best for me was just changing the buildAgent to run under a service account.